# C++ programming try catch

Tags: c++, try-catch

I am allocating memory for an object and if a particular statement following the memory allocation fails, I have to delete the memory and also throw an exception.

For example say

```
               QSqlQuery *query =  new QSqlQuery(db);
               try {
                query->prepare(somestmt);
               }
               catch (...) {
                throwException(*query);
               }
```

Here where and how should I delete query if an exception is thrown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on how long you need the query object to stay alive.  If you don't need it outside the try/except block, then it's probably best to use RAII to delete it as soon as you leave that block.  E.g., using boost::scoped_ptr, you could do this:

```
try {
    boost::scoped_ptr<QSqlQuery> query(new QSqlQuery(db));
    query->prepare(somestmt);
}
catch (...) {
    throwException();
}
```

But from your example, it looks like you want to keep the query object, or a copy of it, around past that block.  If it's ok to just keep a copy of it, then you could do this:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<QSqlQuery> query(new QSqlQuery(db));
try {
    query->prepare(somestmt);
}
catch (...) {        
    QSqlQuery copyOfQuery(*query);
    throwException(copyOfQuery);
}
```

Or this, if you don't like using boost:

```
QSqlQuery* query = new QSqlQuery(db);
try {
    query->prepare(somestmt);
}
catch (...) {        
    QSqlQuery copyOfQuery(*query);
    delete query;
    throwException(copyOfQuery);
}
delete query;
```

If you need to keep the original query itself, then you probably would need to require the exception object itself to delete it.  I.e., do something like this:

```
QSqlQuery* query = new QSqlQuery(db);
try {
    query->prepare(somestmt);
}
catch (...) {        
    throw MyException(query);
}
delete query;
```

Where part of "MyException"'s contract is that it takes ownership of its argument (i.e., responsibility for deleting it).

Another option would be to use shared pointers.  I.e.:

```
boost::shared_ptr<QSqlQuery> query(new QSqlQuery(db));
try {
    query->prepare(somestmt);
}
catch (...) {        
    throwException(query);
}
```

This has the advantage that the query gets deleted when the last shared pointer to it goes away, which makes memory management much easier.

Comment: woof! ;) did you really type all that in 60 seconds? +1 good answer

Comment: You can use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` in place of `boost::scoped_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)** to handle this gracefully.
Either use a smart pointer instead of an raw pointer or use a resource managing class to wrap your allocated pointer so that it releases the allocated object when the scope ends.

Comment: If there are 2 statements inside a try block and first statement throws an exception, will the second statement be executed?

Comment: @user1065969: No, it wont, once throw is called control goes to the catch handler.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your program, if you can retry the prepare and need the pointer to be valid don't delete it, otherwise delete the memeory and idealy set the poitner to null to mark it

edit: sorry misunderstood the question - changed answer

Comment: it is not new that throws exception, it is prepare statemnet

Answer (score 0):

You should learn the [RAII pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).  The idea is to wrap the `QSqlQuery` in a C++ class that does cleanup in the destructor.  That way if it falls out of scope (either by a `throw`, `return`, or reaching the end of the block it is declared in) it is destructed cleanly.

Comment: This query has to be a local variable for me. I have a class variable that is a QScopedPointer to whom I am transferring the ownership of this query once prepare is a success

Comment: If there are 2 statements inside a try block and first statement throws an exception, will the second statement be executed?

Comment: @user1065969: no.  the try block is exited after as soon as an exception is raised, and no subsequent statements are executed.

Answer (score 0):

The usual idiom here is to use an `std::auto_ptr`, calling `reset` on it
once you've gotten far for whatever your program logic depends on to
take over.  This avoids the need for a `catch`.  Since you seem to need
the `catch` anyway (to remap the exception), you can just as easily put
a `delete` there and skip the `std::auto_ptr`.  (On the other hand, one
expects to see the `auto_ptr`, and not having it could cause the reader
to ask questions.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the no-cleanup …

```
           QSqlQuery *query =  new QSqlQuery(db);
           try {
            query->prepare(somestmt);
           }
           catch (...) {
            throwException(*query);
           }
```

just write

```
           QSqlQuery query(db);
           try {
               query.prepare(somestmt);
           }
           catch (...) {
               throwException(query);
           }
```

That's it (assuming `QSqlQuery` has a proper destructor).